# Can not decrypt my gpg file anymore.Any tips?

Tags: arch-linux, gnupg

I have issues decrypting my gpg file. For no reason, i get the following message when I try to gpg -d my encrypted file:

```
gpg: uncompressing failed: Unknown compression algorithm
gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown compression algorithm
```

Did you ecountered the same problem? How did you fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you `gpg --list-packets` it?

Answer (score 0):

I get the following output:

```
Desktop >>> gpg --list-packets parole4.txt.gpg                                 
gpg: uncompressing failed: Unknown compression algorithm
gpg: processing message failed: Unknown compression algorithm
# off=0 ctb=a1 tag=8 hlen=3 plen=31307
:compressed packet: algo=14
```

Comment: Please include this in your question, not as an answer.